# Algorithm - Police and thief in Grid(N*N)

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Problem statement:
Given N*N matrix and each cell in the matrix contains either police or thief.
Find out number of thieves arrested by police.

1. A police can arrest only one thief.
2. Police can arrest thief in the same row.
3. Police can arrest thief within the range of K.(Ex: If K is 1, then police in cell 3 can arrest thieves only in the cell 2 and 4)

Input:
3 1 -> here 3 is N and 1 is K
T P T
T T P
P P T

Output:
3

My solution was timed out for some inputs:

```
1. Iterate each row and have two Treeset<Integer> to store position of police and thief
2. If current item is Police, then check if thief Treeset is Not empty, 
   a.if so then iterate the treeset to find the position from thief set which 
   can be removed(satisfying above criteria), remove thief from treeset and 
   increment counter.
     a.1. If such item not available then add current position to police set
   b. if not then add position to police treeset

3. If current item is Thief, then do the same
```

After iteration complete for a row then iterate for next row and at last print counter.

Taking the time complexity for a row:
1. Iterating every element in a row O(n)
2. Adding or removing element from treeset O(log(n))
Definitely takes more than O(n*log(n))

Please let me know what kind of problem is this and how i should solve effectively.

Comment: what are constraints on N(size of matrix)?

Comment: Hint: the solution should be `O(N^2)`.  There are N^2 cells and each one has to be checked at least once.  But I don't think you need to check an cells more than a constant number of times.  (Based on the algorithm in my head :-) )  That implies `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Now if you were given the positions of the policemen, a solution that is `O(P)` may be possible ... where `P` is the number of policemen.  (That's a bit of a hint for the matrix-based problem too.)

Comment: Okay now I notice outside there, has exactly same question (exact wordings)....it's highly possible that it is some kind of questions of those online competitions, Is it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397308/count-maximum-number-of-thieves-that-can-be-caught

Comment: Yes the same one, it was in a online test

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be solvable with a greedy strategy. You could use queues to store the indexes of polices and thieves, or pointers (one pointer for police, one pointer for thief).

Using pointers (or variables that store indexes), you could do something like this:

1. Declare two variables, e.g. `policeIndex` and `thiefIndex`. For each row:
2. Walk the `policeIndex` to the index of the next police in the row, and walk the `thiefIndex` to the index of the next thief in the row.
3. Compare `policeIndex` and `thiefIndex`:

   3.1. If the absolute difference between them is less than or equal `k`, increase the count of arrests by one. Go back to step 2.

   3.2. Else, walk the lowest index (`policeIndex` or `thiefIndex`) to the next police or thief, depending on the index changed. Go back to step 3.
4. Repeat until `policeIndex` or `thiefIndex` gets to the end of the row, then go to the next row.

With queues you'd do basically the same strategy: fill each queue (police and thief) with all indexes for that type; then get the difference between the first element of each queue, then: if their difference is less than or equal `k`, remove both elements and increase arrest count; else, remove the lowest index from one of the two queues and compare again. Repeat that until any queue is empty.

Comment: Thanks George, My approach is similar but with TreeSet rather than queue or pointer, so I think that's an issue. I don't need a Treeset any ways it going to be stored in order

Comment: @George. i have used the queue but a bit different approach. i have maintained 2 queues. one for police which stores the police index and one for thieves which stores thief index. For each row, if i encounter a police, i look into thief queue.  i keep on popping the thief until i found the first thief who is within the k range. if after all the popping. no element is left in the queue. i enque the police in the police queue. and if there exists some thief within the range,i pop the thief and increment the count.

Comment: and vice -versa, if i encounter a thief i look into police queue and similar steps i follow. Using these steps, i was not able to clear all test cases.

Comment: @Manya, I see you are using ArrayDeque but try using Linkedlist that does not have any removal cost. I'm trying that now, my implementation was same as yours but i used treeset and so for some test cases it timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++:

Vectors can be used instead of iterating again to find indexes.

```
int solution (vector<vector<char> > A, int K) {
    int res=0;
   for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
   {
       vector<int> pol;
       vector<int> thi;
       for(int j=0;j<A[0].size();j++)
       {
           if (A[i][j] == 'P') 
            pol.push_back(j); 
        else if (A[i][j] == 'T') 
            thi.push_back(j);
       }

       // track lowest current indices of 
    // thief: thi[l], police: pol[r] 

       int l = 0, r = 0; 
    while (l < thi.size() && r < pol.size()) {
        if (abs(thi[l] - pol[r]) <= K) { 
            res++; 
            l++; 
            r++; 
        } 
        // increment the minimum index 
        else if (thi[l] < pol[r]) 
            l++;
        else
            r++; 
    }
    pol.clear();
    thi.clear();
   }
   return res;
}
```

It passes all test cases.