# Count maximum number of thieves that can be caught

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

The question goes like this:

There is a **N * N** grid.

1. Each cell of the grid can have either **a police denoted by P** or **a thief denoted by T**.
2. A police can catch a thief only if they are in a same row.
3. A police can catch only one thief.
4. A police cannot catch a thief who is more than **K units away from it**.

Count maximum number of thieves that can be caught.

### Example:

T P T
P T P
T T P

Output : 3

### Approach:

The approach I have used is, a police needs to catch the thief farthest available from him in the given range i.e k. I have implemented this approach using 2 queues, one for policemen and other for thieves.

Out of 24 test-cases 18 got passed, rest got wrong answer.
If the approach is wrong I would like to know the correct answer.
And if some test case I am missing I would like to know that.

Below you can find my code snippet:

### CODE:

```
import java.util.*;
public class policemenAndThief
{
    public int maxThiefCaught(char[][] mat,int k)
    {
        int count = 0;
        ArrayDeque<Integer> police = null;
        ArrayDeque<Integer> thief = null;
        int n = mat.length;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            police = new ArrayDeque<>(n);
            thief = new ArrayDeque<>(n);
            for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
            {
                if(mat[i][j] == 'T')
                {
                    while(police.isEmpty() == false && j - police.peekFirst() > k)
                    {
                        police.pollFirst();
                    }

                    if(police.isEmpty())
                    {
                        thief.addLast(j);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        police.pollFirst();
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    while(thief.isEmpty() == false && j - thief.peekFirst() > k)
                    {
                        thief.pollFirst();
                    }

                    if(thief.isEmpty())
                    {
                        police.addLast(j);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        thief.pollFirst();
                        count++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay now I notice outside there, has exactly same question (exact wordings)....it's highly possible that it is some kind of questions of those online competitions, Is it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397091/algorithm-police-and-thief-in-gridnn

Comment: yes @shole . it is from an online competition which has already got over.

Comment: Thanks for your honesty Manya. Can you please provide the link?

Comment: The competition was hosted on hackerearth. and since the competition is completed, i am not able to see the problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @talex. When i submitted my solution. Only 18 out of 24 testcases passed. I would like to know if there is some test cases i missed or if the approach i wrong. In the latter case i would like to know the correct approach

Comment: Question like this is off-topic here.

Comment: @talex . so where can i ask it if not here?

Comment: @Manya Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @talex. i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linked list:

```
int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String row = N_A[i];
            LinkedList<Integer> policeList = new LinkedList<>();
            LinkedList<Integer> thiefList = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                char c = row.charAt(j);
                int jk = j + 1;
                if (c == 'T') {
                    boolean add = true;
                    while (!policeList.isEmpty()) {
                        int p = policeList.pollFirst();
                        if ((jk - p) <= k) {
                            count++;
                            add = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (add) {
                        thiefList.add(jk);
                    }

                } else {
                    boolean add = true;
                    while (!thiefList.isEmpty()) {
                        int t = thiefList.pollFirst();
                        if ((jk - t) <= k) {
                            count++;
                            add = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (add) {
                        policeList.add(jk);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ Solution:

```
int solution (vector<vector<char> > A, int K) {
    int res=0;
   for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
   {
       vector<int> pol;
       vector<int> thi;
       for(int j=0;j<A[0].size();j++)
       {
           if (A[i][j] == 'P') 
            pol.push_back(j); 
        else if (A[i][j] == 'T') 
            thi.push_back(j);
       }

       // track lowest current indices of 
    // thief: thi[l], police: pol[r] 

       int l = 0, r = 0; 
    while (l < thi.size() && r < pol.size()) {
        if (abs(thi[l] - pol[r]) <= K) { 
            res++; 
            l++; 
            r++; 
        } 
        // increment the minimum index 
        else if (thi[l] < pol[r]) 
            l++;
        else
            r++; 
    }
    pol.clear();
    thi.clear();
   }
   return res;
}
```

It passes all 24 test cases.